# Using twig to set HTML inline style

Tags: html, twig

I am new to using twig HTML and getting there slowly. I am trying to set the style in a widget as follows:

`div class="progress xs">
  <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-blue" style="width: {{percent}}%;"></div>
</div>`

However the % character gives the error: unexpected character sequence, expected a selector for the style rule, and the progress bar does not show the correct percent. Can someone explain what I am doing wrong here.

thanks

Derek

Comment: What is the value of `{{percent}}`?

Comment: percent is 86% but looks like 60 on the progress bar

Comment: Your answer isn't clear. What's the exact variable value?

Comment: Sorry about late response, laptop problems. I found my problem - I used the wrong variable. I thought the problem was due to the WebMatrix error message, which at the end of the day was not an error. Thanks for the responses.